# Does Spring-Data-Neo4j has any parameter/configuration where we can point to the intended Database?

Tags: spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4jclient

I am on Neo4j Desktop and I have a project where I have 2 Databases under one Instance(DBMS).

So is there any property/configuration that tells SDN the right Database it has to query into?

In my Spring boot app, when I try to query the database with SDN, it queries the wrong Database and returns "Provided Label not present in Database" error.

I am following the same steps as mentioned in [this article](https://louisjj.medium.com/multiple-datasources-for-springboot-neo4j-4-x-mysql-920727dfbb80), but the example uses two different Neo4j DB hosts, wherein I have to use two different Neo4j Databases in same Host.

This is a POC project inside VDI machine where SOF is restricted, Hence unable to share implementation here - but hope the question is quite generic.

Answer (score 3):

[As documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#faq.multidatabase), you can statically specify the database name using the spring config property `spring.data.neo4j.database`, or you can dynamically specify the database name per transaction via a [DatabaseSelectionProvider](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/neo4j/core/DatabaseSelectionProvider.html) bean.

Comment: But I have the correct Database mentioned in the spring.data.neo4j.database property and it still queries the wrong DB. Why I am sure about this is the same query that returns no matching properties in API works fine on the intended DB via Neo4j desktop.

Comment: Just to be sure: are you specifying `spring.data.neo4j.database` as a Spring property (e.g., in the `application.properties` file)? It does not belong in `neo4j.conf`.

Comment: Absolutely, I have even implemented the DatabaseSelectionProvider bean and confirmed that the intended database name is getting passed in the method argument.

Comment: And I forgot to mention that I am using Neo4j Desktop. Not Community or Enterprise server.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it is intended to work this way - but I tried the same app on Neo4j enterprise edition and I was able to connect with the right Database mentioned by `spring.data.neo4j.database` property. But it is not working on Neo4j Desktop.